# custom post types, custom fields and normalization

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, database, design

I have decided to redesign a plug I developed to use custom post types and custom fields instead of custom tables in the database.

I have some questions about abstracting data into new post types. These questions are based on the assumption that I should essentially be trying to replicate a relational database.

It's a dictionary feature for a language learning blog. Here are the tables from the original. Simplified for readability.

```
CREATE TABLE words (
    ID int(),
    word varchar(),
    parent_id int()
);

CREATE TABLE nouns (
    word_id int(),
    plural varchar(),
    [...]
);

CREATE TABLE verbs (
    word_id int(),
    pres_part varchar(),
    past_part varchar(),
    [...]
);

CREATE TABLE definitions (
    ID int(),
    word_id int(),
    definition varchar(),
    [...]
);

CREATE TABLE examples (
    ID int(),
    defintion_id int(),
    example varchar(),
    [...]
);
```

Words will obviously be the first custom post type.

I've decided to use custom fields for the noun and verb information as they are 1:1 relationships and only existed to reduce null entries in the words table. 
I believe WordPress will only create an entry in the postmeta table if the fields are actually used. So that would solve that problem.

Now the main question is; should I store definitions and examples as custom post types as I would in a relational database or just use ACF repeaters? These are both genuine 1-many relationships. Although a single definition will probably only ever have a maximum of 3 examples.

The reader might wish to search for keywords within the definitions and/or examples but they would never want to view a single definition as page.

Definitions and examples might however be used outside the context of their respective word in the future. With a flashcard app for example. Is it easy to uniquely identify and request a single entry from a repeater?

Comment: Because ACF stores everything as postmeta, site performance typically suffers if you are querying by any of those values. Repeaters are especially tricky to work with as far as querying goes. It sounds like you'd be better off looking more into custom taxonomies and assigning those - they can still be assigned to multiple posts but that way you can do a `tax_query` which is much faster to run than a `meta_query`.

Comment: Honestly, going from custom tables to posts and postmeta feels like a step _backwards_.  Using posts and postmeta comes with a lot of compromises, especially in terms of performance. There's a lot of questions here where the best solution would be custom tables, if that was within the asker's skill level, so if you've already got a working custom database structure, that seems like a good thing. Was there something you were hoping to gain from using posts?

Comment: Thanks @WebElaine. Are you suggesting to store the definitions and examples as categories and sub-categories respectively? eg. a taxonomy called "to say something using your voice" assigned to the post "to speak". and a sub-category called "Could you speak more slowly, please?" as a child of "to say something using your voice"

Comment: Thanks @JacobPeattie. That's encouraging actually. But yes... I want viewable pages for each word. I'm beginning to realise that a complete switch might be an overreaction. Perhaps I just need a "word" custom post type and then I can bring all the other tables into those posts with metaboxes. I guess I was caught up on trying to shoehorn my project into what WordPress offers.

Comment: Not Categories (capital C as they are an out-of-the-box WP feature) but custom taxonomies. So, you might have a taxonomy called "definition" where individual taxonomy terms are the individual definitions. And a taxonomy called "example" where the individual terms would be individual examples. But as Jacob mentioned, this does sound like something where custom tables might be an even better solution. Individual "words" as a CPT would work and you could then use the `single-word.php` theme template to pull in all the custom table data.